# Getting AT&T Velocity USB dongle on Ubuntu 16.04 server

Tags: command-line, server, usb, modem

Preface:
 This device works fine when connected to the Desktop version of Ubuntu. It creates a new network interface and provides Internet connectivity.

But, when I try to connect it to the Server edition, the network interface is not created.

Details:
 Dongle: AT&T Velocity USB (ZTE MF861)

Log shown by dmesg:

```
[ 1883.698974] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
[ 1883.848256] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=19d2, idProduct=1405
[ 1883.848263] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1883.848268] usb 1-2: Product: ZTE Mobile Broadband
[ 1883.848271] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: ZTE,Incorporated
[ 1883.848274] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: MF8610ZTED000000
[ 1883.873568] cdc_ether 1-2:1.0 usb0: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-0000:00:14.0-2, CDC Ethernet Device, xx:yy:zz:aa:bb:cc
[ 1883.884895] usb-storage 1-2:1.2: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 1883.885327] scsi host7: usb-storage 1-2:1.2
[ 1883.890212] cdc_ether 1-2:1.0 enp0s20f0u2: renamed from usb0
[ 1884.884482] scsi 7:0:0:0: CD-ROM            ZTE      USB SCSI CD-ROM  2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[ 1884.886942] sr 7:0:0:0: [sr0] scsi-1 drive
[ 1884.887332] sr 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
[ 1884.887493] sr 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 5
[ 1888.176279] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 12
[ 1888.176364] cdc_ether 1-2:1.0 enp0s20f0u2: unregister 'cdc_ether' usb-0000:00:14.0-2, CDC Ethernet Device
[ 1889.127002] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
[ 1889.276301] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=19d2, idProduct=1405
[ 1889.276307] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1889.276312] usb 1-2: Product: ZTE Mobile Broadband
[ 1889.276315] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: ZTE,Incorporated
[ 1889.276318] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: MF8610ZTED000000
[ 1889.299753] cdc_ether 1-2:1.0 usb0: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-0000:00:14.0-2, CDC Ethernet Device, xx:yy:zz:aa:bb:cc
[ 1889.307434] usb-storage 1-2:1.2: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 1889.307934] scsi host8: usb-storage 1-2:1.2
[ 1889.312973] cdc_ether 1-2:1.0 enp0s20f0u2: renamed from usb0
[ 1890.308585] scsi 8:0:0:0: CD-ROM            ZTE      USB SCSI CD-ROM  2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[ 1890.311823] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr0] scsi-1 drive
[ 1890.312058] sr 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
[ 1890.312185] sr 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 5
[ 2087.529644] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial
[ 2087.529654] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial_generic
[ 2087.529662] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for generic
```

Can anyone guide me on how to get this working?

I tried contacting ZTE support, but they wouldn't offer Linux troubleshooting.

*Edit*
The output of dhclient -v enp0s20f0u2 is:

```
sc@sc:~$ sudo dhclient -v enp0s20f0u2
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.3
Copyright 2004-2015 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/enp0s20f0u2/xx:yy:zz:aa:bb:cc
Sending on   LPF/enp0s20f0u2/xx:yy:zz:aa:bb:cc
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s20f0u2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3    (xid=0xf2cb26af)
DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.1.153 on enp0s20f0u2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x6f2bafc2)
DHCPOFFER of 192.168.1.153 from 192.168.1.1
DHCPACK of 192.168.1.153 from 192.168.1.1
bound to 192.168.1.153 -- renewal in 39672 seconds.
sc@sc:~$
```

Comment: You probably need to edit `/etc/network/interfaces` to cover your device. Before I propose a solution, please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `sudo dhclient -v enp0s20f0u2` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 Added the output in the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you edit the file `/etc/network/interfaces` to something like:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp0s20f0u2
iface enp0s20f0u2 inet static
address 192.168.1.25
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1 8.8.8.8
```

I suggest a static address so that you can ssh and ftp into the server. Be sure to select a static address outside the range used by the DHCP server in the router, switch or other access point.

Get the system to read and use the changes:

```
sudo ip addr flush dev enp0s20f0u2
sudo ifdown enp0s20f0u2 && sudo ifup -v enp0s20f0u2
```

Did you connect?

```
ping -c3 192.168.1.1
ping -c3 www.google.com
```

It might take a reboot.

Comment: Got this after restart:

ifdown: interface enp0s20f0u2 not configured
Configuring interface enp0s20f0u2=enp0s20f0u2 (inet)
/bin/run-parts --exit-on-error --verbose /etc/network/if-pre-up.d
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/ethtool
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/ifenslave
+ [ inet = meta ]
+ IF_BOND_SLAVES=
+ [  ]
+ [  ]
+ [ -z  ]
+ exit
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/vlan
/bin/ip addr add 192.168.1.3/255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.1.255    dev enp0s20f0u2 label enp0s20f0u2
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Failed to bring up enp0s20f0u2.

Comment: SO just seems to be getting rid of all newlines, no matter how I post it. Sorry for the messed up output.

Comment: Also, when the interface is coming up, I see the message:

cdc_ether 1-2:1.0 enp0s20f0u2: kevent 12 may have been dropped

Not sure how important this is, but thought it'd help.

Comment: So, did you get the requested address? `ifconfig` Do the pings work?

Comment: I got the requested address, but the pings don't work.

Comment: Please see my edit above in a few minutes.

Comment: The ip addr flush dev command resulted in the **cdc_ether 1-2:1.0 enp0s20f0u2: kevent 12 may have been dropped** output. And, the results are the same (no pings)

Comment: Oh wait.. On the fourth re-try, this seems to be working. Thank you so much.